# SQL find total time based on state change timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following rows

[image]

How to write a query to have the following output between a start and an end date

[image]

Comment: the expected results don't seem to be correct

Comment: Can you open a box already open?

Comment: What timestamps are supposed to give you the difference in seconds? Are you comparing the minimum open to the maximum open? Or are you comparing the minimum open to the maximum close?

Comment: yes @vkp. i just realized that i have only taken the diff of the sec part.

Comment: the query would have a time span specified using 'between' so we calculate the lower limit and upper limit of the last stated based on the span provided.

Comment: @David Isla : you cannot . Its just a "poll" kind of thing happening randomly.

Comment: Is your data bad? It looks like b1 is opened twice then closed once.

Comment: Data is not bad. Thats just how it appears in a feed.